# NullPointerException in my code. How to deal with it

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've written my code in Java using Selenium. When I run the code, it's throwing a NullPointerException. Check the exception below

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at AdminInterface.loginApplication(AdminInterface.java:17)
    at AdminInterface.main(AdminInterface.java:29)
```

My code is as follows:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
public class AdminInterface {
    public WebDriver driver;
    public void launchApplication() throws Exception
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\Users\\rprem\\Downloads\\IEDriverServer_x64_3.4.0\\IEDriverServer.exe");
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.gcrit.com/build3/admin/");
    }
    public void loginApplication(String Username, String Password)
    {
        driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys(Username);
        driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys(Password);
        driver.findElement(By.id("tbd1")).click();
    }
    public void closeBrowser()
    {
        driver.close();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        AdminInterface obj = new AdminInterface();
        obj.loginApplication("admin", "admin@123");
    }
    }
```

Comment: You haven't called `launchApplication` method, where you actually initialize the webdriver object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeing a `NullPointerException` because from `main()` you are trying to access the `loginApplication()` method right in the begining, which requires an active instance of the `WebDriver` i.e. the `driver` to `findElement(By.name("username"));` & `findElement(By.name("password"));` and perform `sendKeys()` method on the `HTML DOM`.

The solution would be to first access the `launchApplication()` method so you have an active instance of `driver` and `IE Browser`. Next you can access `loginApplication()` method.

Here is your working code block:

```
package demo;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;

public class Q45474353_NPE 
{

    public WebDriver driver;
    public void launchApplication()
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\IEDriverServer.exe");
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.gcrit.com/build3/admin/");
    }

    public void loginApplication(String Username, String Password)
    {
        driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys(Username);
        driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys(Password);
        driver.findElement(By.id("tbd1")).click();
    }

    public void closeBrowser()
    {
        driver.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Q45474353_NPE obj = new Q45474353_NPE();
        obj.launchApplication();
        obj.loginApplication("admin", "admin@123");
        obj.closeBrowser();
    }

}
```