# NullPointerException while running selenium

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, testng

Am getting null NullPointerException when running below code, i am just trying read excel path from properties file but getting error, please help me as I'd tried hard to resolve this problem

login script

```
public class Login1 {
    public static Properties props;
    public static WebDriver driver;
    public InputStream propertiesFilePath = this.getClass().getClassLoader()
    .getResourceAsStream("Config.properties");

    public static void main(String [] arg){
    }

    public  void Readproperties() throws IOException {
        props = new Properties();
        props.load(propertiesFilePath);
    }

    public static void  getDriver(){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",               "C:\\Users\\aroy\\Desktop\\Sele\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }
    public static void logintoapp(String acc, String passw){
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='userName']")).sendKeys(acc);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='password']")).sendKeys(passw);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='loginBtn']")).click();
        System.out.println("Login SuccessFully");
    }
}
```

Tesstcase:

```
package AtExecution;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import BeoreExecution.Login1;

public class Testcase extends Login1 {

    public static ExcelLib exel1;

    @Test
    public void login() throws IOException{
        Login1 x = new Login1();
        x.Readproperties();

        exel1 = new ExcelLib(Login1.props.getProperty("TestDataPath"));
        String siteurl = exel1.getCellData("Login_Credentials",    "TestUrl", 2);
        String acc = exel1.getCellData("Login_Credentials", "account", 2);
        String passw=exel1.getCellData("Login_Credentials", "Password", 2);
        Login1.getDriver();
        driver.get(siteurl);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        Login1.logintoapp(acc, passw);
    }
}
```

here is my log

```
    [RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.12.0
     FAILED: login
     java.lang.NullPointerException
     at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
     at java.util.Properties.load0(Unknown Source)
     at java.util.Properties.load(Unknown Source)
        at BeoreExecution.Login1.Readproperties(Login1.java:30)
     at AtExecution.Testcase.login(Testcase.java:18)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at            org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:669)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:877)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1201)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:776)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:634)
```

Please help me to solve this

my config file data is

TestDataPath=C:/Users/Testdata.xlsx

and below is my exelsheet data

[link to excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhmkM.jpg)

Comment: Why initialize your WebDriver in your other class? Why not just initialize it in your test case class, then pass it as a parameter to a constructor in your other class?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NullPointerException in my code. How to deal with it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45474353/nullpointerexception-in-my-code-how-to-deal-with-it)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did't instantiate WebDriver instance in your test case class. You can follow the below way:

Return WebDriver from the method -

```
public static WebDriver  getDriver(){
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",               "C:\\Users\\aroy\\Desktop\\Sele\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    return driver;
}
```

Then call this method inside login test method like

```
WebDriver driver = Login1.getDriver();
```

Finally continue your next code.

Comment: @Abhijith how did you call the getDriver() method? Can you send me your implemented code in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) box.

Comment: Hi Ali, i cant able to create box

Comment: Login1 x = new Login1();
   x.Readproperties();
   
   exel1 = new ExcelLib(Login1.props.getProperty("TestDataPath"));
   String siteurl = exel1.getCellData("Login_Credentials", "TestUrl", 2);
   String acc = exel1.getCellData("Login_Credentials", "account", 2);
   String passw=exel1.getCellData("Login_Credentials", "Password", 2);
   Login1.getDriver();
   driver.get(siteurl);
   driver.manage().window().maximize();
   Login1.logintoapp(acc, passw);

Comment: @Abhijith Can you please send you getDriver method definition also?

Comment: pls find getdrivermethod

Comment: public static WebDriver  getDriver(){
     System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\aroy\\Desktop\\Sele\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
     driver = new ChromeDriver();
     return driver;
 }

Comment: @Abhijith please come on [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) and upload both the class file.

Comment: @Abhijith when you call the method, use the line `WebDriver driver =  Login1.getDriver();` instead of `Login1.getDriver();`

Comment: Hi Ali, i cant come to chat as it is saying i need 20 reputation but i have only 1

Comment: i call the method as suggested by you only

Comment: Hi Ali, my Skype id is +91 98863 47751

Comment: Ali, Pls come to skype or provide me your mail id i will send my class files

Comment: @I am in a hurry. so attach the file and I will give you the solution later.

Comment: Sure ali, i sent aatachments

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the below snippet of your code

```java
public InputStream propertiesFilePath = this.getClass().getClassLoader()
    .getResourceAsStream("Config.properties");

    public  void Readproperties() throws IOException {
        props = new Properties();
        props.load(propertiesFilePath);
    }
```

Java is not finding a resource by the name `Config.properties` in your CLASSPATH. You would need to check and ensure that this file is available in the CLASSPATH and is readable by Java. Once this is fixed, your `NullPointerException` should go away.

Comment: i added my Config.properties in src/directories, any thing i am missing pls guide me