# Receiving "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException" when using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

When using this class in Selenium WebDriver:

```
package Selenium3;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

public class Jobs {

static WebDriver driver;

public Jobs(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
}

public static void con() throws InterruptedException {
    List<WebElement> element = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".position_title.ng-binding"));
    for (int i = 0; i < element.size(); i++) {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        String u = element.get(i).getText();
        if (u.contains("Java"));
        System.out.println(u);
    }
  }
}
```

The driver is always null. In the end I want to call this method from my Main class. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you're obviously not instantiating your driver

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NullPointerException in my code. How to deal with it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45474353/nullpointerexception-in-my-code-how-to-deal-with-it)

Answer (score 3):

You have an `static` method (that not requires class instantiation)... so when you call the method without instantiating the class you wont initialize your driver:

You have various solutions:

- **Make method not `static`** *(you will force initialization of driver with constructor, but you can reuse the instantiated class various times)*

  ```
  public class Jobs {

      private WebDriver driver;

      public Jobs(WebDriver driver) {
         this.driver = driver;
      }

      public void con() throws InterruptedException {
          List<WebElement> element = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".position_title.ng-binding"));
          for (int i = 0; i < element.size(); i++) {
              Thread.sleep(2000);
              String u = element.get(i).getText();
              if (u.contains("Java"));
              System.out.println(u);
          }
  }
  ```
- **Keep method `static` adding driver as a parameter** *(so you will have your driver prior to call method and you won't need to instantiate the class)*

  ```
  public class Jobs {
      public static void con(WebDriver driver) throws InterruptedException {
          List<WebElement> element = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".position_title.ng-binding"));
          for (int i = 0; i < element.size(); i++) {
              Thread.sleep(2000);
              String u = element.get(i).getText();
              if (u.contains("Java"));
              System.out.println(u);
          }
  }
  ```
- **Use a `static` block to initialize the driver** prior the method static call *(faster to call, but problem is you cannot chuoose which driver implementation you will use)*

  ```
  public class Jobs {

      static WebDriver driver;

      static {
         this.driver = new FirefoxDriver(); // just an example
      }

      public static void con() throws InterruptedException {
          List<WebElement> element = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".position_title.ng-binding"));
          for (int i = 0; i < element.size(); i++) {
              Thread.sleep(2000);
              String u = element.get(i).getText();
              if (u.contains("Java"));
              System.out.println(u);
          }
  }
  ```

Comment: `WebDriver` is an interface. Change to `new FirefoxDriver();` the line with comment :)

Comment: thanks @RafałLaskowski :) you make me think about a new option

Comment: Hi @assaf-sagee as you're a new user and you never marked a question as answered I think you must know if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. Of course, there is no obligation to do this.